# C++ vector of objects: assigning the objects

Tags: c++, vector, graph

I have to make a hex board for a class and I have an issue with my code. My graph has a 2D vector of nodes for the board. Each node has a vector of neighbor nodes. I can't seem to assign the neighbor nodes into the vector.

node class:

```
class node{
public:
    string hex_type = "E";// empty to start
    vector<node> neighbors;
    int Xcoordinate;
    int Ycoordinate;



class graph{
public:
    int size;
    graph() { this->size = 11; }
    graph(int a){ this->size = a; }
    vector<vector<node> > nodes; 

void initialize(){
        int x, y;
        int max = this->size-1;
        this->nodes = vector<vector<node> >(size, vector <node>(size));
        for (x = 0; x < size; ++x){ 
            for (y = 0; y < size; ++y){
                //this->nodes[x][y] = node();
                this->nodes[x][y].Xcoordinate = x;
                this->nodes[x][y].Ycoordinate = y;
                this->nodes[x][y].neighbors = vector<node>(6);
                if ((x == 0) && (y == 0)){ this->nodes[x][y].neighbors[0] = this->nodes[x + 1][y]; }

                }

            }
        }
};
```

my print statement here only outputs a series of numbers: -842150451

```
cout <<  this->nodes[0][0].neighbors[0].Xcoordinate;
```

Comment: how is that the Xcoordinate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when this->nodes[x][y].neighbors[0] = this->nodes[x + 1][y]; is excuted, x = 0, y = 0. nodes[1][0] haven't initalized.
you can initlize all the nodes first .

```
for (x = 0; x < size; ++x){ 
            for (y = 0; y < size; ++y){
                //this->nodes[x][y] = node();
                this->nodes[x][y].Xcoordinate = x;
                this->nodes[x][y].Ycoordinate = y;
            }
        }
for (x = 0; x < size; ++x){ 
            for (y = 0; y < size; ++y){
                //this->nodes[x][y] = node();
                 this->nodes[x][y].neighbors = vector<node>(6);
                 if ((x == 0) && (y == 0)){ this->nodes[x][y].neighbors[0] = this->nodes[x + 1][y]; }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`.neighbors[0] = this->nodes[x + 1][y];` that's making a *copy* of the node.  A copy of a node you haven't initialized yet.  Ergo the copy has nonsense values.

You probably want `vector<node*> neighbors;`, so it holds pointers to it's neighbors, rather than copies.

If so, it would be

```
.neighbors[0] = &(this->nodes[x + 1][y]);
                ^
```

Comment: the line of code: this->nodes[x][y].neighbors[0] = this->nodes[x + 1][y] would change to.....?